# How do I have a child element's height even across cards with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

**EDIT:** Updating to clarify that this doesn't need to use `flex` and looks like `grid`/`subgrid` is the direction to go. My example uses `flex` because that's what I was familiar with.

---

How do I, with CSS only, get the title (blue) box to match the height of the biggest title box in the row. The red box should then fill the rest of the space and the stat cards will evenly fill the red box.

Current Layout
[image: Current Layout]

Desired Layout
[image: Desired Layout]

I've seen solutions that use JavaScript, but would like to avoid that if possible. The "Desired Layout" screenshot is using a fixed height on the title box to demonstrate.

```css
body {
  background-color: #454545;
  color: #fafafa;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1em;
  &__title {
    background-color: blue;
    //height: 100px;
    padding: 0 1em;
  }
  &__content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 1em;
  }
}

.stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.stat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0 1em;
  min-width: 145px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__title">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <div class="stats">
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 2</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 3</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__title">
      <h3>TItle lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <div class="stats">
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>They're just warming up!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__title">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <div class="stats">
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 2</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Code Pen:** https://codepen.io/Maynards/pen/NWJYvzq

Comment: Flexbox is one-dimensional. It has no knowledge of what's going on in other columns. You want [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Comment: Looks like what you actually want is for `card__title` to be a certain height across all `card`s, `card_content` to take up the remaining height. then each `stat` is evenly spaced within `stats`.

Comment: Not sure what the downvote was for, very happy to use Grid if it helps solve the problem :), but knowledge of Grid is early days. I'm trying to avoid `card__title` having a fixed height as well.

Answer (score 1):

As a few have pointed out, using `grid` is the way to go. I was able to achieve the desired result using `subgrid` . Browser support seems to be pretty good now for `subgrid`, so I'll be using that.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #454545;
  color: #fafafa;
}

.cards {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2rem;
  max-width: 1080px;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: subgrid;
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
  gap: 0;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 1em;
}

.card__title {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.card__content {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 1em;
}

.stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.stat {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 0 1em;
  min-width: 145px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__title">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <div class="stats">
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 2</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 3</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__title">
      <h3>Title long lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <div class="stats">
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>They're just warming up!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__title">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <div class="stats">
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 2</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>Content</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__title">
      <h3>Title lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card__content">
      <div class="stats">
        <div class="stat">
          <div class="stat__title">
            <h4>Stat 1</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="stat__content">
            <p>They're just warming up!</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box;  }
.contener_1 {
  display         : flex;
  flex-direction  : row;
  gap             : .6rem;
  }
.contener_2 {
  display         : flex;
  flex-direction  : column;
  justify-content : flex-end;
  width           : 30em;
  gap             : 0;
  }
.contener_2 > div {
  border       : 10px lightcoral solid;
  padding      : .7rem;
  }
.contener_2 > div:first-of-type {
  flex-grow    : 1;
  border-color : lightblue;
  }
.contener_2 > div:not(:first-of-type) {
  height       : 10em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="contener_1">
  <div class="contener_2">
    <div><h4>Stat 1</h4><p>Content</p></div>
    <div><h4>Stat 2</h4><p>Content</p></div>
    <div><h4>Stat 3</h4><p>Content</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="contener_2">
    <div><h3>TItle lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h3></div>
    <div><h4>Stat 1</h4><p>They're just warming up!</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="contener_2">
    <div><h4>Title</h4></div>
    <div><h4>Stat 1</h4><p>Content</p></div>
    <div><h4>Stat 2</h4><p>Content</p></div>      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's nice, but not quite like the desired layout. As others have eluded to, Grid/Subgrid appears to be the way to go.